# How Do I Insert Data I Pulled From A SQL Table I Assigned To A Dictionary<int, int>?(ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I assigned two int values (`CampaignId` and `LinkId`) from one SQL Server table to a `Dictionary<int,int>` variable and now I am trying to insert it into another SQL Server table. What do I need to do to get each data value I assigned to the dictionary into the

```
command.parameters.Add(@UserAgent, ????)
```

and

```
command.parameters.Add(@LinkId, ????)
```

My code

```
string queryString = "SELECT CampaignId, LinkId FROM TrackClick WHERE UserAgent IS NOT NULL;";         

var UserDetails = new Dictionary<int, int>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();

    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        UserDetails.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetInt32(1));
    }
}
 
var insertString = @"INSERT INTO dbo.User_Details (CampaignId, LinkId,)
                     VALUES (@CampaignId, @LinkId)";

using var connection = new SqlConnection(con);
            //code to insert the insertString

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertString, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CampaignId",/* ????*/);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LinkId",/* ????*/);

connection.Open();

// insert bulk Records into DataBase.  
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple rows, you might try an INSERT SELECT statement.  This would get away from parameterization of your query, which is normally a bad thing.  But you are not inserting user input so SQL injection is not as much of a concern.
So you'd just need to loop through your dictionary and do string concatenation on the SQL statement

```
insert into dbo.User_Details ( CampaignId, LinkId,)
SELECT @CampaignId1, @LinkId1
UNION ALL
SELECT @CampaignId2, @LinkId2
```

etc...